# New to python: why does random.choice() produce correctly when alone but when placed in a name expression it doesnt

Tags: python, random

If I do `random.choice` by itself, I get the desired result, but if I place it in a name expression, I don't. The reason I ask is because I'm making a rock paper scissor game and I need the computer to randomly choose between the three, and from what I've read it's not practical to use `random.choice` all on its lonesome. What would be the ideal solution? Thanks.

Ex:

```
>>> import random
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> comprandom = random.choice(l)
>>> comprandom
1
>>> comprandom
1
>>> comprandom
1
>>> comprandom
1
>>> comprandom
1
>>> comprandom
1
>>> random.choice(l)
3
>>> comprandom
1
>>>
```

Comment: As an aside, `random.randrange(1, 4)` might be more appropriate, or even better, move it to 0 based and use `random.randrange(3)`. This would also be more compatible with lists (say if you had `["rock", "paper", "scissors"]` you could index it with the random choice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others have said, what you are doing is assigning the result of `random.choice(l)` to `comprandom`

If you want to alias the function in python3, you should be able to do the following

```
l = [1,2,3]
randch = random.choice
print(randch(l))
```

Answer (score 8):

When you type `comprandom` in an interactive prompt, you aren't repeatedly calling `random.choice(l)`. You're simply requesting that python return you the current value of the variable `comprandom`.

You should  call `random.choice(l)` every time you need a new random number.

Answer (score 3):

In the following line:

```
>>> comprandom = random.choice(l)
```

You are assignin **comprandom** to a random item in list **l**. However, after you assign it, if you want to reassign **comprandom** to another random value, you must use **random.choice()** again, as follows to reassign the value:

```
>>> comprandom = random.choice(l)    
>>> print(comprandom)
2
>>> comprandom = random.choice(l)
>>> print(comprandom)
1
```

The reason being that variables themselves are assigned to values, and not to functions.